# Should I fully trust JWT content

Tags: authorization, jwt

So I am using JWT authentication, then I want to implement authorization. Some resources only available for users with admin role for example.

If I put the role in the token, is it a good idea to take that as a truth without double checking whether the user actually is an admin by making request to database? I was thinking if I can do that, then I can save 1 database or API call to check the current user role.

Also, I appreciate that the content in the token won't be 100% up to date, for example if the admin role is revoked when the token is still alive then technically the content is not true, but I can live with that, my worry is more about if the token content can be tampered by user in any way, but that shouldn't be the case... right?

Comment: If you have a well implemented JWT backend, the user cannot tamper with it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A properly signed JWT token cannot be practically manipulated, provided that the signature is also properly checked. But ...

JWT supports unsigned tokens (`"alg":"none"`). Without signature tampering with the token cannot be detected.  Additionally issues in the implementation of the JWT library might allow an attacker to change the algorithms to `none` and disabling signature validation this way - see [Critical vulnerabilities in JSON Web Token libraries](https://auth0.com/blog/critical-vulnerabilities-in-json-web-token-libraries/).

Answer (score 1):

You are pretty accurate on both.

First, you have to check the validity of the token. Valid algo, signature, expiration... As long as the signing key is kept secret and not leaked outside, you are on the safe side and the JWTs cannot be tampered with.

Secondly, the token is usually valid for some predefined time. Even if this user's role is changed within that time, the token itself will remain valid until it expires, with all its associated permissions.

Therefore, as a rule of thumb, for non-critical stuff, I would thrust the JWT, but if the requested operation is sensitive, I would double check with the database in order to verify if the user's permissions are indeed still valid.

Comment: Thanks, I think your answer is right but the other answer provide more details about possible vulnerability so I accept that one instead. In terms of practical implementation, your suggestion seems sensible, can't be hurt to double check the most critical stuff to be on the safe side.

Comment: @morgan9999 Sure. This is a simplified answer since technicalities can go very deep. For example, the `"alg":"none"` is a low hanging fruit that most libs reject. But things might be more sneaky, like applying the public key to symmetric signing algos https://auth0.com/blog/critical-vulnerabilities-in-json-web-token-libraries/ or simply get the private key hacked because it is too short (since you can brute force offline) and many other curlpits. You could fill whole blogs about it. But, if you do it all right and validate them correctly, yeah they are safe.

Comment: sorry for the late follow up ...somehow this post popped up in my "inbox", dunno why. Never mind.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

According to *Applied Cryptography - Protocols, Algorithms, and Source Code in C*
[A book by Bruce Schneier](https://www.schneier.com/books/applied-cryptography)

> These numbers have nothing to do with the technology of the devices;
> they are the maximums that thermodynamics will allow. And they
> strongly imply that brute-force attacks against 256-bit keys will be
> infeasible until computers are built from something other than matter
> and occupy something other than space.